# NULL compare using CodeIgniter ActiveRecord

Tags: codeigniter

I've got a table like this.

```sql
[id]     [name]     [age]
1        foo        20
2        bar        NULL
```

If i need to return all the rows when age's fields is NULL i do the following and it works fine.

```php
$this->db->from('person')->where('age', null);
```

The problem is that i need to do the opposite, i mean, return all rows when the age fields are not null values.
In SQL i do something like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM person WHERE age is not null
```

How do i do this using CodeIgniter ActiveRecord ??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: hope this will help http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/119444/P15

Comment: are you setting the ALLOW NULL DEFAULT NULL mysql options to your db fields?

Comment: This is the way of multiple comparison in where command
$where = array('somebit' => '1', 'status' => 'Published', 'sc_id' => TRUE );
$this->db->where($where);

Comment: The thread referenced above by @sbaaaang is now at https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/119444/P15

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use:

```
$this->db->from('person')->where('age is not null');
```

If you curious how this happens see `system/database/DB_active_rec.php`

```
protected function _where($key, $value = NULL, $type = 'AND ', $escape = NULL)
{
    ...

        if (is_null($v) && ! $this->_has_operator($k))
        {
            // value appears not to have been set, assign the test to IS NULL
            $k .= ' IS NULL';
        }

        ...
}
```

And `system/database/DB_driver.php`

```
/**
 * Tests whether the string has an SQL operator
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @return  bool
 */
function _has_operator($str)
{
    $str = trim($str);
    if ( ! preg_match("/(\s|<|>|!|=|is null|is not null)/i", $str))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

As a result you could pass just first parameter to `where()` method and if first operator of this method has a sub string `is not null` it will be left untouched.

To read more - [CodeIgniter forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/119444/P15)

Answer (score -1):

This must be the way:

```
 $this->db->from('person')->where('age IS NOT NULL', null);
```

Comment: I try that and it doesn't work. The ActiveRecord tries to compare the field with NULL, but NULL doesn't compare equal to anything, so, it reports a sql syntax error.

Comment: Try where('age IS NOT NULL', null)

Comment: look at the method signature `public function where($key, $value = NULL, $escape = TRUE)` - the second parameter in not obligatory.

Comment: yes @mallix that works fine but like alphacentauri said, null in that case is not required.